# How do I handle instant spikes in traffic in my APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using aws for my cloud infrastructure. I use ecs fargate as my compute machine. I am currently maintaining 10-20 apis which interact with members who have my application downloaded on their phone. Obviously one or two of these apis are my "main" apis and these are the ones which are really personalised to my users and honestly, these are the only two apis which members really access (by navigating to those screens).

My business team wants to send push notifications to members to alert them on certain new events which lands them on a screen where these APIs need to be called. Due to this, my application has mini crashes during this time period.

I've thought of a couple of ideas for the same, but since this is obviously an issue across industries and a solved problem, I wanted the standard solutions.

The ideas I have:

- Sending notifications in batches. This seems like the best solution though it requires a bit of effort though I'm not sure how much.
- Have a serverless machine run my requests (aws lambda functions) for those APIs which need to scale instantly. I have a lot of other APIs which I keep in fargate because I don't want my lambda function to be too heavy and then take a while to start up.
- Scale machines all the time to handle the load I get during push notifications. This seems suboptimal due to cost reasons.
- Scale machines up just during those periods where I want to send push notifications and them scale them back down. This seems like a decent solution if I can automate the entire process. I can have a flow which I follow for each push notification which will cause the system to scale and then start sending the notifications.

Is there a better way to do this. This seems like a relatively straightforward problem for people to have, but I don't see too much information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I like your second option best because it's by far the easiest to manage (because you don't have to manage it). After that I'd go with your last option. I would use step functions to manage this, where the first step is to scale up the number of instances in Fargate. Once that has reached the desired level you would send the notifications. Add autoscaling to your services in Fargate to have it handle coming down automatically.

Comment: The second one might be a bit more complex than it looks though. It might not necessarily be scaleable and if I want to cache certain information, it will become a tough task. Leaning towards the fourth solution because it requires the least effort but I'm unsure whether I should even suggest this decision to the higher ups in my company because it seems really intrusive on our devops. Though fargate scaling is amazing, I'm still a bit scared.

Comment: The lambda approach could be an issue if what is behind it doesn't handle it well. It also could lead to some code rewrites. I don't know what "intrusive on our devops" means, but it sounds like you have another team that manages these things and you'd have to have them do some of that work. There isn't anything about it that you can't do yourself, assuming you have the correct permissions. Either way, DevOps is intended to make things like this easier, not harder.

Comment: I guess I meant infrastructure rather than devops. I wouldn't want to be tinkering with the number of machines just because someone wants to send a push notification. This will also mean that I will need to maintain stricter control over who can send push notifications and other complications. I know it isn't tough, I've written our deployment scripts because I was a part of devops for the first few months!

Comment: The beauty of this is that if they have autoscaling turn on the worst that happens is you bring up some extra instances for a few minutes when you shouldn't have. Then autoscaling will bring it back down.

Comment: That's true. I'm guessing this is a standard problem which all people using push notifications have though, right? How is this generally handled?

Comment: I don't know that there are a lot of people doing pushes to their entire user base at once. At least not one that would cause a mass increase in volume for a very short period of time. Your batching option isn't the worst idea, depending on the message.

Comment: I think the batching idea is the best non intrusive way to do it. I'll let my team know both these things and let us see what they think about each of them. Seems like a straightforward path from a technical standpoint with either approach. It's just that batch calling will also be more extensible once the number of members increase whereas if I use the increasing compute capacity, I'll need to keep varying this everytime the number of total members changes. Thanks for your help.